Creating two executables from a spring-boot maven project
I have spring-boot maven micro-service. Now I want scheduler functionality within this project. As micro-service may be running as multiple instances, I think keep scheduler in the same project will result in multiple executions of the same scheduler. So I want to create another executable jar with the same project. I don't want all the dependencies of micro-service in this executable. How I can accomplish this?

Why can the scheduler not run in all instances? It would be much cleaner and easier to understand if all instances were able to run the scheduler.

Obviously, I don't want same scheduled task run multiple times.

Think it through. If we cannot run the scheduled tasks in multiple deployments, this means that every release comes with a downtime and possibly manual actions (stopping the old release, starting the new release). Depending on what the scheduled task is doing, it could also profit from load balancing when multiple pods share the work.

Don't we need to guarantee that all the scheduled tasks run once only?

Maybe. Depends on the system. Maybe "at least once" is acceptable. Maybe "exactly once" is necessary.

Have a table with a row per task and lock the relevant row pessimistically, to incarnate a distributed lock. Depending on the db server, some neat sql can help a lot, like mysql 8 with "select ... for update nowait" or "... skip locked" (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/select.html). If you don't have a db, there is zookeeper that can help if you have one, but that's another central point of failure. The above idempotency suggestion is fair if feasible.
